# javascript object error

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototypejs

This is my situation:

```
var r = {"id":"test","files":[],"code":""};


var Page = Class.create({


 initialize: function(json) {
  this.id = json.id;
  this.json = json;

 },
        start: function() {
  this.json.files.each(function(x) {
   var cssResource = this.pageResource(x, 'css');
   this.attachCssResource(cssResource);

  }.bind(this));
        },

//etc....

});

var P = new Page(r);
P.start();
```

Hi have this.json.files.each is not a function.. why?

I use prototype 1.7 library.

if i use this

```
var P = new Page({"id":"test","files":[],"code":""});
```

i have NO error??....

Comment: Isn't [] a notication for 'an object' which does not have the 'each' method. I think it should be {} for an Array, which does supply the .each method.

Comment: @Marvin Smit no, `[]` is an empty array.

Comment: Note that he's using prototype, NOT jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to extend the PrototypeJS functions on your array to get the each function to work:

```
$A(this.json.files).each(function(x) {
   ...
}
```

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-a

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/extend

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting only ECMAScript 5 platforms you will want to use `Array.forEach`.

**15.4.4.18 Array.prototype.forEach ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )**

*callbackfn* should be a function that accepts three arguments. forEach calls *callbackfn* once for each element present in the array, in ascending order. *callbackfn* is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

If a *thisArg* parameter is provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of callbackfn. If it is not provided, **undefined** is used instead.

*callbackfn* is called with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the object being traversed.

forEach does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but the object may be mutated by the calls to *callbackfn*.

The range of elements processed by forEach is set before the first call to *callbackfn*. Elements which are appended to the array after the call to forEach begins will not be visited by *callbackfn*. If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to forEach begins and before being visited are not visited.

Comment: He's using Prototype, which does all sorts of things to native types.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can forcibly cast it to an array with:

```
$A(this.json.files).each(...
```

Sometimes I find it easier to work with a hash instead of an array -- `$H` instead of `$A`.